# Python/Pyramid: Will this function let users upload files and then parse them?

Tags: python, file-upload, pyramid

Right now I have this form:

```
<form action="/store_stl_data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="stl">STL</label>
    <input id="stl" name="stl" type="file" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

then in my `views.py` I have

```
@view_config(route_name='store_stl_data', renderer='templates/edit')

def store_stl_data(request):
    input_file=request.POST['stl'].file
    i1, i2 = itertools.tee(input_file)
    vertices = [map(float, line.split()[1:4])
                for line in i1
                if line.lstrip().startswith('vertex')]

    normals = [map(float, line.split()[2:5])
                for line in i2
                if line.lstrip().startswith('facet')]

        ...(parsing data)...
    return data
```

The three lines under `def store_stl_data(request):` are the ones I am most unsure about. I got them from [this tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/forms/file_uploads.html).

I want it so that when people upload the file, the entire `store_stl_data` function runs and processes the input file.

Right now it gives me an error:

```
KeyError: "No key 'stl': Not a form request"
```

Also here is my route, in `__init__.py`:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

from .models import (
    DBSession,
    Base,
    )


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('view_wiki', '/')
    config.add_route('view_page', '/{pagename}')
    config.add_route('add_page', '/add_page/{pagename}')
    config.add_route('edit_page', '/{pagename}/edit_page')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Comment: looks okay to me.  have you tried it?

Comment: If you've got the code, it should be easy to see what it does and whether it works. Remember to write tests, too!

Comment: `input_file` is already an open file object. You do not need to open it again.

Comment: I have updated the code and the error message that it shows

Comment: why do you have `store_stl_file` and `store_stl_data` ?  are there two functions, or is one the route name to the function name ?

Comment: oops. good catch. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The `.file` object you get from the request is already an open file(like) object.

If you look closely at the example in the documentation you linked to, it creates a *new* file using the filename of the upload, and uses the uploaded file to write data to that new file. `input_file` is never opened in that code, *only `output_file`* is (note the different variable name there).

You do not need to close the file object either, so no `with` is needed. Your code can be simplified to:

```
def store_stl_data(request):
    input_file=request.POST['stl'].file
    i1, i2 = itertools.tee(input_file)
    vertices = [map(float, line.split()[1:4])
                for line in i1
                if line.lstrip().startswith('vertex')]

    normals = [map(float, line.split()[2:5])
                for line in i2
                if line.lstrip().startswith('facet')]
```

I personally would *not* use `itertools.tee` for this though, you are reading the whole file into the `tee` buffer while building vertices.

Instead, I'd use a single loop:

```
def store_stl_data(request):
    input_file=request.POST['stl'].file
    vertices, normals = [], []
    for line in input_file
        parts = line.split()
        if parts[0] == 'vertex':
            vertices.append(map(float, parts[1:4]))
        elif parts[0] == 'facet':
            normals.append(map(float, parts[2:5]))
```

Now only one line at a time is kept in memory (plus the vertices and normals structure).

*Note*: If you get a `KeyError: No key '...': Not a form request` error message, then the view did *not* receive a `POST` HTTP request. Do double check your form method is set to `"POST"` (case does not matter).

Comment: thanks for the tip. I have updated the question and my code with your solution although it now gives me an error (refer to the question)

Comment: You did upload a file? The 'stl' key is not present in the post.

Comment: No, I have updated my code in response to your answer. The key error referenced in the now updated question occurs when I attempt to submit the form

Comment: Okay, the exact error means that you didn't make a POST request. Are you certain that you have the right route / form / handler set up?

Comment: I have added the route (__init.py__) to my question. As for the form and handler, I was under the impression that these are the @view_config and def store_stl_data function respectively Is this not true?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: There is nothing there that tells my why you don't make a proper POST to the view.